# Why does CoffeeScript not support `==`?

Tags: coffeescript

I am learning CoffeeScript and am using [js2.coffee](http://js2.coffee/) to convert my Javascript file to CoffeeScript. One some lines, it warns me that

```
Operator '==' is not supported in CoffeeScript, use '===' instead.
```

What is the rationale behind that? **Why does CoffeeScript not support `==`?**

Comment: ["Because the == operator frequently causes undesirable coercion, is intransitive, and has a different meaning than in other languages,..."](http://coffeescript.org/#operators).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the same reason that most Linters warn you against using it.

It's a strangely implemented operator with surprising side-effects.

```
"\n\t" == false
// => true
```

There are many things written on the topic, but most notably the `==` operator made Douglas Crockford's list of [things to avoid](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html).

Comment: So CoffeeScript has taken this a step further and ***imposes*** that it's not allowed?

Comment: Yes. CoffeeScript has only `===`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually CoffeeScript compiles `==` to JavaScript's `===` (and `!=` to `!==` as you can see in the [documentation](http://coffeescript.org/#operators)).

So bottom line yes, it doesn't support it. I guess it is because `==` does type conversion before checking equality **if** the operands are of different type. This conversion is a practice that has been frowned upon because of its *unexpected results* and its *performance*.

There is much discussion online on the issue of `==` vs `===`. [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) helped me get a better understanding on the issue.